# How can I create a dataframe with random numbers columns, each with a different range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for a way to create a random dataframe with 3 columns and 3 rows, but from which the random numbers of the first column should be in the range [1:5], the second in [1:8] and the third in [4:10].

Example from what I need:

```
   A  B  C
0  4  3  9
1  1  4  10
2  4  8  4
```

I know how to create a random dataframe with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,size=(3, 3)))
```

But I can't find a way of adding these ranges as a condition per column. I can generate three random numbers and then add them together as dataframe, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = 3
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=np.random.randint(1, 6, size=n),
    B=np.random.randint(1, 9, size=n),
    C=np.random.randint(4, 11, size=n)
))

df

   A  B  C
0  3  5  6
1  1  7  6
2  1  1  4
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(3, 3) * [5, 8, 7] + [1, 1, 4],
    columns=list('ABC')
).astype(int)

df

   A  B   C
0  3  6  10
1  3  5   7
2  4  6   7
```